# Как правильно сделать архитектуру для высоко нагруженного проекта и какую выбрать БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel

Задача сделать портал подобный пульсу цен - pulscen.ru
Что требуется:
- Основной сайт(test.ru) - авторизация/регистрация, создание под сайта, панель управлением, товары с под сайтов, фильтр
- Под сайты(*.test.ru), которые создаются автоматический при создании на основном сайте

Я захожу на основной сайт(test.ru), регистрирую свою компанию и автоматически создается сайт d3.test.ru(3 - порядковый номер нового сайта ++) выдаются права на редактирования данного сайта

Я могу добавить товар, при добавлении товара на мой новый сайт(d3.test.ru) нужно чтобы он дублировался на основной сайт test.ru

На основном сайте показываются все товары, которые были добавлены на под сайтах(*.test.ru) с указанием компании, адреса сайта на котором был добавлен товар

Как я это сделал:

За основу взят framework laravel и бд MySQL
Решил сделать 2-е отдельные платформы
1 - для основного сайта портала test.ru
2 - для всех под сайтов *.test.ru
Обе платформы подключены к одной базе

Немного о том как все устроено

1 - основной сайт test.ru
В бд используются таблицы

categories - Общие категории для использования на под сайтах *.test.ru
id | title | slug | description | photo | meta_title | meta_description | view

prods - Все товары с под сайтов *.test.ru
id | title | slug | up_text | down_text | category_id | price | nalichie | dostavka | rating | meta_title | meta_description | view

sites - Все созданные сайты
id | name | site_url | email | phone | city_id | rating | prefix | rating

2 - под сайты *.test.ru
Для каждого под сайты используется свой фаил с конфигурацией .env в нем отличия только в префиксе для БД
Для каждого под сайта используются свои таблицы, они отличаются префиксом d3_(3 - порядковый номер сайта)

d3_prods - Все товары сайта d3.test.ru
id | prod_id | title | slug | up_text | down_text | category_id | price | nalichie | dostavka | rating | meta_title | meta_description | view - появился новый столбик prod_id в нем указан id товара расположенного на основном сайте
То есть при добавлении товара на под сайт d3.test.ru товар сначала добавляется в таблицу d3_prods, затем пользователь выбирает публиковать/не публиковать на портале test.ru и если да, то это товар добавляется в таблицу prods - от сюда берем его id и обновляем поле prod_id в таблице d3_prods для этого товара (поле prod_id нужно, в случае редактирования товара на под сайте, чтобы по prod_id найти товар в таблице prods и в нем также изменить данные)

d3_settings - настройки для под сайта(название, описание, логотип, телефон, емаил, адрес)
d3_seos - сео настройки для страниц(meta_title, meta_description)
d3_pages - динамические страницы

И пока все шло не плохо, но когда уже было создано более 150 под сайтов и добавлено более 5мл товаров, все начало ужасно виснуть, в БД практически не реально зайти

При том, что используется на мой взгляд хороший сервер
Процессор 26 X Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz
Оперативная память 6000 / 30249 MiB (в среднем используется / всего)
Размер дискового пространства 4.19 TiB

Вопрос?
Как правильно сделать структура БД для подобной задачи, какую БД выбрать?

Comment: а пробовали смотреть, какие запросы самые медленные? может там индексов не хватает?

Comment: Могу предложить несколько вариантов. 1. Каждый сайт разворачивать на свой машине (можно виртуальной), со своей БД. Публикация на основной сайт будет осуществляться через API, а не прямой запрос в БД. 2. Сделать одну общую глобальную БД для всех сайтов. Настроить репликацию, балансировщик.

Comment: В качестве ответа на подобный вопрос можно несколько книжек написать.  ) Самое первое - выделить под БД отдельный сервер, потом выделить несколько серверов, настроить репликацию между ними, на какое-то время этого должно хватить, с ростом нагрузок - шардинг. И это только БД. Так же нужно думать в сторону кеша, отложенных вычислений, распределенных вычислений, балансировок.

Comment: + само собой анализ запросов, как написали выше, их оптимизация

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, запросы не проверял, к сожалению индексы вообще не используются, буду экспериментировать. Просто сейчас составляет трудность просто попасть в БД phpmyadmin, в большинстве случаев сайт отдает 504 ошибку, сейчас там примерно 600+ таблиц

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо, 1 варианты интересный, но как тогда лучше поступить на пример с файлами сайта, сейчас получается, что за все под сайты отвечает 1 платформа и при ее изменении файлов этой платформы, все изменяется на всех под сайта. А для вашего варианта придется изменять вручную для каждого сайта?

Comment: @СергейКоновалов Спасибо, сейчас по возможности большинство запросов кэшируются. Буду думать о выделенном сервере под БД и по изучаю отложенные вычисления, распределенные вычисления, а что такое балансировка?

Comment: @nicolaa начните с индексов. Если индекса нет, а Вы хотите найти по условию (`where filed == 'test'`) - то это сканирование всей таблицы. А с индексами может быть логарифм. И скорость сразу ощутите.Но какие индексы и где - это Вам смотреть. Начинайте с этого https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+slow+log+%D0%B2+mysql%3F

Comment: Начните с индексов. 80% вопросов производительности уйдут сами собой. Ручной вариант изменения придётся делать, если вы не напишите автоматический скрипт загрузки изменений. А сделать это можно, если очень захотеть.