# Как распределить mysql на несколько серверов

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте исходя из [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113460/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82)(индексы сделаны), решил попробовать сделать несколько серверов

На 1 сервере хранить файлы cms
На 2 и 3 сервере хранить БД

На данный момент БД занимает 4 гб, как возможно равномерно распределить БД по 2-м серверам?

Смотрел в сторону репликации, но как я понял репликация полностью дублирует таблицы БД мастера
А у меня должны получиться разные таблицы на каждом сервере
В принципе я сейчас могу в ручную распределить таблицы по серверам
Но встает два вопроса, как в дальнейшем делать это в автоматическом режиме и как делать запросы к БД на другом сервере?
Например у меня сейчас есть 10 таблиц и я через join получаю информацию с 10 таблиц, а как быть если 5 таблиц переедут на другой сервер

Или это все на данный момент не имеет смысла и нужно просто воспользоваться репликацией и равномерно распределить запросы на чтение на 2 сервера?
Хочется сделать 1 раз и не переделывать